# nodejs - include iv with encrypted file data

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I'm refactoring this code to encrypt files to fit it inside a class.

```js
    async encryptData(file, password){  
        this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(32);
        this.key = crypto.scryptSync(password, this.salt, 32);
        //this.buffer = await fs.readFile(file.tempFilePath);
        this.base64 = dataURI.getBase64DataURI(file.data, file.mimetype);
        this.iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        this.cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', this.key, this.iv);
        this.encryptedData = Buffer.concat([this.cipher.update(this.base64, 'utf8'), this.cipher.final()]);
        this.output = `${this.iv.toString('hex')}:${this.encryptedData.toString('hex')}`;
        //fs.writeFile(...)
    }
```

The objective is to encrypt a file after converting it to base64 using a library that will mantain the mime type that is used later to decrypt and save the file into the original format. In my last line of code I have the ´output´ variable that will create a string that will contain the `iv` and the encrypted data. Is there a better way to include the `iv` with the data so I can avoid to use the `toString()` function? If this is possible, how I can get the iv and the data when I need to decrypt the file?

**UPDATE:**

After some test and after the suggestion in the answer to remove the base64 file encoding I've refactored the code in this way. Seems working fine, but any suggestion to improve it will be appreciated.

```js
    async runServer(){
        this.app.post('/encrypt', async (req, res) => {
            let password = req.body.password;
            for(let file in req.files){
                await this.encryptData(req.files[file], password);
            }
            //res.send({});
        });
    
        this.app.post('/decrypt', async (req, res) => {
            let password = req.body.password;
            for(let file in req.files){
                await this.decryptData(req.files[file], password);
            }
            //res.send({});
        });
    }
    
    async encryptData(file, password){  
        this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(32);
        this.key = crypto.scryptSync(password, this.salt, 32);
        this.iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        this.cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', this.key, this.iv);
        this.encryptedData = Buffer.concat([this.salt, this.iv, this.cipher.update(file.data), this.cipher.final()]);
        this.output = path.format({dir: this.tmpDir, base: file.name});
        await fs.writeFile(this.output, this.encryptedData);
    }

    async decryptData(file, password){
        this.salt = file.data.slice(0, 32);
        this.key = crypto.scryptSync(password, Buffer.from(this.salt, 'binary'), 32);
        this.iv = file.data.slice(32, 48);
        this.encryptedData = file.data.slice(48);
        this.decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', this.key, this.iv);
        this.decryptedData = this.decipher.update(this.encryptedData);
        this.output = path.format({dir: this.tmpDir, base: file.name});
        await fs.writeFile(this.output, this.decryptedData);
    }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

As suggested I've implemented the GCM required tag. If I'm not wrong it will have a length of 16 bytes. I'm not sure where I need to pass it into decryption process and how to extract it.

```js
//file encryption 
this.encryptedData = Buffer.concat([this.salt, this.iv, this.cipher.update(file.data), this.cipher.final(), this.cipher.getAuthTag()]);

//file decryption
this.salt = file.data.slice(0, 32);
this.key = crypto.scryptSync(password, Buffer.from(this.salt, 'binary'), 32);
this.iv = file.data.slice(32, 48);
//How I extract the GCM tag at the end of the data?
//this.tag = file.data.slice(48, 64);
this.encryptedData = file.data.slice(48);
//Where I should pass the extracted GCM tag?
this.decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', this.key, this.iv);
this.decryptedData = Buffer.concat([this.decipher.update(this.encryptedData), this.decipher.final()]);
```

Comment: You should consider the authentication tag. You _force_ decryption without authentication by omitting the `final()` call. Decryption without authentication is generally insecure. Apart from that, for GCM authentication is the plus over simple encryption. Also, I'm not sure if a missing `final()` call is _robust_ (i.e. always works). Furthermore, keep in mind that _most_ libraries do not allow decryption without valid authentication for security reasons, i.e. your ciphertext can only be decrypted by that libraries that don't authenticate, which makes you dependent on those libraries.

Comment: Where I need to implement the `final()` in decryption? Before calling the `update()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, IV and ciphertext are concatenated at the binary level. If conversion to a string is necessary, use a suitable [binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding), e.g. Base64:

```
var encryptedData = Buffer.concat([iv, encryptedData]).toString('base64')
console.log(encryptedData)
```

The IV is not secret and therefore may be sent unencrypted. Also, a separator (like `:`) is not necessary because the IV has the length of the block size (16 bytes for AES), so the criterion for separation is known:

```
var encryptedDataBuffer = Buffer.from(encryptedData, 'base64')
var iv = encryptedDataBuffer.slice(0, 16)
var ciphertext = encryptedDataBuffer.slice(16)
```

Hexadecimal could also be used as binary-to-text encoding (but this is less efficient at 50% than Base64 at 75%). If the ciphertext has to be URL safe, [Base64url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) can be applied instead of Base64, or [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) can be performed.

Since you are using GCM, the (non-secret) authentication tag must also be taken into account. This seems to be missing in your code. The tag is determined with [`cipher.getAuthTag()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_getauthtag), is needed for decryption (more precisely for authentication during decryption) and is typically appended to the ciphertext: `iv|ciphertext|tag`. Separation of the tag is feasible, because the length of the tag is known (defaults to 16 bytes).

Also, for each key generation a new, random (non-secret) salt should be generated, which is to be concatenated analogously: `salt|iv|ciphertext|tag`.

By the way, Base64 encoding of the file *before* encryption is generally not necessary, actually the binary data can be encrypted. Base64 encoding only increases the amount of data.

Comment: I'm not a security expert so I've missed out some points. I've not included the GCM tag because the user will send the file to the server with a password so I'm realying on the user password to do the encryption process. Also for the salt I think it's automatically generated when the class method is called from the `for` loop I have to iterate the files to encrypt/decrypt, see the updated code

Comment: how I can append the tag to the generated encrypted data?
`Buffer.concat([this.salt, this.iv, this.cipher.update(file.data), this.cipher.final()]);` According to the docs, the tag needs to be generated after `cipher.final()` function is called, but in my code I'm using it to generate the final output to write

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've implemenyed it but need some help to understand how and where I need to pass the extracted tag into decryption. See question update

Comment: @newbiedev - The link in my last comment  also contains an example for decryption. Have you had a look at it? No offense, but authentication was not the topic of the original question (and I only mentioned it in passing in my answer). For more details, a separate question would probably make more sense, simply because it's more manageable than updates and comments.